# How to cancel request by tag in retrofit 2?

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit2, okhttp

Is there way we can cancel a specific request by tag in retrofit 2 just like Volley.
In volley we can cancel request by doing this.

```
sRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(appContext);


public void enqueueRequest(Request req) {
    sRequestQueue.add(req);
}


public void cancelTaggedRequests(String tag) {
    sRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
}
```

is there any similar way in Retrofit 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel request by calling `call.cancel();`

Another way use RxJava and create Subscription and un-subscribe respected request.

```
if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
  subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: In case of RxJava, how can we cancel that?